# How to write a query instead of the keyword OR?

Tags: android

The Case 1 works well, but Case 2 don't work, is there a simple to way to instead of the keyword OR  ?

**Case 1**

```
public List<String> getSMS(int pos) {
        List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse(valueList.get(pos));
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null,"_id= '6' or  _id= '4' ", null,
                null);

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
            String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body+" CW  "+cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id")) );

        }
        return sms;
    }
```

**Case 2**

```
public List<String> getSMS(int pos) {
        List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse(valueList.get(pos));
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null,"_id in ['6','4'] ", null,
                null);

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
            String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body+" CW  "+cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id")) );

        }
        return sms;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem in using OR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  this in your case 2..

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null,"_id in ('6','4') ", null,
                null);
```

See if this works...